# 'import intake' in google colab generates ContextualVersionConflict

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, intake

```
!pip install intake-esm
```

install the latest version of intake-esm (2020.12.18)  in google colab

but the `import intake` statement generates the following error:

```
ContextualVersionConflict: (requests 2.23.0 (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('requests>=2.24.0'), {'intake-esm'})
```

could anybody please tell me what is going wrong or how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

At first install  `intake-esm`

```
!pip install intake-esm
```

Then install `astropy >= 3.1` and `sunpy`

```
!pip install astropy>=3.1
!pip install sunpy
```

Finally, import `intake`

```
import intake
```

Following this, I can import `intake`.

Comment: Would love to know the versions that get installed at each stage, where the origin of the error is. Is there anything Intake can do to clarify versions?

Comment: Thanks! But it didn't help. Still generates the error.

Comment: I started again in a new notebook. Now the error not showing  :)